# XML Relationship

Tags: xml

Dupe:  [XML Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433528/xml-relationship)

---

I am unable to define a relationship between paper and author. Is it possible to define one?

```
<xsd:complextype name="Researcher'>
</xsd:complextype>
<xsd:complexType name = "Paper" >
      <xsd:extension base = " Researcher " >
      </xsd:extension>
  </xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name = "Author">
      <xsd:extension base = " Researcher ">
      </xsd:extension>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Need just a tad more information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Since the 'X' in XML stands for extensible, there are *many* ways to do it, hence James Atkinson's comment. Here's a simple example:

```
…
<author id="1">
    <name>
        <first>James</first>
        <last>Joyce</last>
    </name>
</author>
…
<book>
    <title>Ulysses</title>
    <author refid="1" />
</book>
…
```

Of course, you're probably not the first person to solve this sort of problem, so I'd look around for an open standard. Try googling "Dublin Core" and "ISBN" and see if anything pops up.